# C# Authentification Form via PageMethods

Tags: ajax

I have a problem regarding those tutorials : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

I ve create my own site with those tips, so on my HTML file, I ve of course insert inside the form :

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

I've create a Logon.aspx page in order to put the login form, and by click, the button call a javascript function login():

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            var user     = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            PageMethods.login_GO(user, password, ok, ko);
            function ok(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
            function ko(result) {
                alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

then the javascript function call a behind code method (inside the Logon.aspx.cs file)

```
[WebMethod]
public string login_GO(string user, string password)
{
    if (user == "cool" && password == "whau")
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user, true);
        return "done";
    }
    else
    {
        return "KO";
    }
}
```

The only answer I have is an alert messagebox from the browser:

Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.

Why do you think this method doesnt work ?

I mean normally I dont need anything else isnt ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT:

Before I started to debug the code, I decide to disable the Authentication feature in the Web.config configuration (I only put a comment on all those lines below) :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"  defaultUrl="PlazaMonitor.aspx" >
</forms>
</authentication>    
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>-->
```

So now, I can call the login_GO method on the behind code (Logon.aspx.cs).

Every works fine, but not the Authentication (because I disabled it)

The goal of all of this, is to authenticate an user using a behind code method, so if I need to be Authenticated before I use the Authentication Method I m going to be crazy ^^ !

EDIT :

I just understand, EVERY ressource should be disabled until you are AUTHENTICATE, so even the WebMethod used to be authenticate is disabled !

Do you know where (in Web.config certainely) we could change/allow the good ressources we need ?

Thanks in advance for your help ;) !

Comment: You're getting that alert because you created that alert in the code.  What is the actual contents of `result` (which you're currently ignoring)?  What is the actual response from the server?  When you debug this server-side, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for helping ! I m not sure about what you re talking, I mean, regarding my code, the only reason I put result, is to now if the function login_GO() is really called. Normally, after clicking on the button I just want to be authentify... like in the tutorial. The only problem in the tutorial Logon.aspx is that when we click on the button, the script launched is in the same file than the site ... so all the users could see the login and the password.... that s why I d like to put the function on the server side...

Comment: My point is that you need to debug this.  There's a good chance that the system is telling you what's wrong and you're just ignoring it.  If your `ko` JavaScript callback function is being invoked then presumably that means there was an unsuccessful response from the server for the AJAX call, right?  So you need to determine what that response actually is.  Use your browser's debugging tools to examine that response.  Use your .NET debugging tools to examine what's happening in the server-side code when the AJAX call is made.  We can't debug this on your computer for you.

Comment: You re right David ;) , I ll check this out

Comment: David ? could you read my EDIT comment ? I have news...